# ¿como calcular una ubicación este dentro de un radio usando google maps?

Tags: javascript, html5, google-maps, geolocalización, geolocation-api

Lo que pretendo hacer es obtener mi ubicación y la otra ubicación de un lugar estatico dentro de google maps,
Lo que pretendo hacer es cuando mi ubicación se encuentre dentro de esa radio me mande un mensaje que estoy en ese lugar. Alguien sabe algun metodo
que me facilite este trabajo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## GeoLocation.watchPosition

Para interactuar con la posición de una persona se usa el api [GeoLocation](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Geolocation) de HTML5.

Específicamente, para mantenerse monitoreando una posición, se usa el método [watchPosition](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/watchPosition), cuyan disponibilidad debieras verificar en el browser, pero   hoy en día [casi todos cumplen](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-api_geolocation_watchposition).

Al invocarlo te pedirá permiso para saber tu posición

```
  navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
    pos => {
      let {coords: {latitude, longitude} = {}} = pos;
      console.log({latitude, longitude});
    },
    err => {
      console.warn('Error en el localizador',err);
    },
    {timeout: 30000, maximumAge: 60000}
  );
```

El error se gatillará cuando se agote el timeout, cuando la persona te niegue el acceso a su ubicación (o bien los headers del sitio bloqueen el permiso por [Feature Policy](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/06/feature-policy#header))

Las opciones como timeout y maximumAge están documentadas en [PositionOptions](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/PositionOptions)

Si tu idea es monitorear hasta que la persona llegue a un sector, no querrás seguir alertándolo una vez que entró en él, así que tienes que pensar en una manera de quitar el watcher.

Para eso, cuando declaras el watcher obtienes un ID, que puedes usar para "matarlo" cuando ya haya cumplido su labor.

```
let listenerId;

listenerId = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(...);

// Cuando ya no lo quiero tener escuchando
navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(listenerId);
```

## Combinándolo con Google Maps

Google tiene una librería de funciones geométricas que puedes pedir como extra cuando incluyes la librería: (donde dice libraries=geometry)

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=quarterly&libraries=geometry&key=<tu_key>"></script>
```

Con esa librería en el espacio de nombres, tienes acceso a la función [computeDistanceBetween](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/geometry#spherical.computeDistanceBetween)

```
google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(puntoA,puntoB)
```

Uno de tus puntos es fijo. Digamos que tiene latitud 20 y longitud 30:

```
const puntoFijo = new google.maps.Latlng(20,30);
```

Entonces ahora, cuando el watchPosition te responda, haces la verificación:

```
let listenerId;

listenerId = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
 pos => {
   let {coords: {latitude, longitude} = {}} = pos,
   actual = new google.maps.Latlng(latitude,longitude),
   distancia = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(puntoFijo,actual);
   if(distancia<1000) { // 1km
     alert('estás a menos de un kilómetro');
     navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(listenerId);
   }
   console.log({latitude, longitude});

 },
   err => {
      console.warn('Error en el localizador',err.code, err.message);
    },
    {timeout: 30000, maximumAge: 60000}
);
```

Si no quieres visualizarlo en un mapa, no es necesario recurrir a Google Maps. Puedes hacerlo por ejemplo con [@turf/distance](https://github.com/Turfjs/turf/tree/master/packages/turf-distance), parte de la suite TurfJS

Answer (score 0):

Segun veo tu inquietud quieres un tipo de Alarma que te avise cuando estas entrando en una zona, ahora no estás aclarando si quieres programar o bajo qué lenguaje lo quieres lograr, otra cosa que te puedo recomendar es el uso de Alarma en  Teléfonos inteligentes. existen apps que te hacen esa labor.en el caso de Android [Location Alarm](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.btonape.locationalarm) y en el caso de iOs [Alarm OnePlace](https://itunes.apple.com/es/app/alarm-on-place/id1234840835?mt=8)
En el caso de querer hacer una especie de DApp te recomiendo uses valores de posicionamiento y definir las coordenadas de proximidad. Espero sea de tu ayuda.

Comment: Ah pense que con especificar con las etiquetas sabrian, lo quiero hacer en ionic obviamente hacerlo con javascript, y si es casi similar a las apps que mencionaste, pero ahora no se como se realiza o que metodos se ocupan, con eso tendria para investigar y hacerlo por mi mismo