# Cómo obtener el location de un usuario cuando entra a una website con MapBox GL?

Tags: php, javascript, map, geolocalización, mapbox

estoy tratando de agregar algunas funcionalidades de Geolocalización a mi website, usando la API de Mapbox pero me encuentro con el problema de que no se cómo hacer para obtener la localización de cada usuario que entra a mi website, específicamente quiero obtener sus coordenadas.

Tengo este codigo de Mapbox:

```
mapboxgl.accessToken = '<-token de usuario va aqui->';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: 'map', // container id
  style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
  center: [-96, 37.8], // starting position
  zoom: 3 // starting zoom
});

//Add geolocate control to the map.
map.addControl(
 new mapboxgl.GeolocateControl({
   positionOptions: {
     enableHighAccuracy: true
   },
    trackUserLocation: true
  })
);
```

Con este codigo yo obtengo un mapa, con un botón, que al darle click lleva a cada usuario a su localización en el mapa.
Lo que yo quisiera lograr es obtener las coordenadas de esa localización pero sin mostrar el mapa en los usuarios, obtener todo en "background" por asi decirlo.

Alguna idea o ayuda que puedan darme para resolver este problema? Lo agradecería mucho.

Si con Mapbox no es posible esto, me podrian sugerir alguna otra opción para lograr esto?

Answer (score 0):

Revisa esta respuesta: [¿como calcular una ubicación este dentro de un radio usando google maps?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/310471/como-calcular-una-ubicaci%C3%B3n-este-dentro-de-un-radio-usando-google-maps/311890#answer-311890). Ahí se habla de un método que va actualizando la posición. En tu caso es sólo saber la posición al ingresar (para centrar el mapa imagino).

El control de mapbox por debajo aplica el API nativo de HTML5 para geolocalizar. Si acaso alguno de los requisitos del API falla, o el proveedor no responde (el browser lo determina?) o hay timeout, no funcionará. **Consejo: usa el API nativo para ver el error, o revisa la consola por si mapbox ya lo está imprimiendo.**

Los requisitos son:

1. que el browser del usuario soporta HTML5 Geolocation API (casi todos hoy en día)
2. tu sitio se sirva con HTTPS
3. El header `Feature Policy` permita usar esa API

Entonces el siguiente código preguntará al usuario que confirme un cuarto requisito, que es el permiso del usuario para compartir la ubicacion

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
  successFunction, 
  errorFunction, 
  options={}
)
```

successFunction es una función que espera un objeto [GeolocationPosition](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/GeolocationPosition) mientras que errorFunction espera un [GeolocationPositionError](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GeolocationPositionError). La verdad he visto que a veces el error se le pasa a successFunction, tendrás que probarlo.

```js
function gotPosition(pos) {
  // imprime e.g.  {coords: {lat: -33, lng: -73, accuracy: 1 }}
  console.log({
    pos
  });
}

function gotError(err) {
  console.warn(err);
}


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(gotPosition, gotPosition, {
    enableHighAccuracy: true,
    timeout: 5000,
    maximumAge: 0
  });
});
```

(en stack overflow el Feature Policy impide pedir ese permiso. Puedes verlo en https://codepen.io/amenadiel/pen/poJmbzE
)

## WorkArounds

**Si tienes control del servidor:**

Puedes obtener una aproximación general usando MaxDB GeoIP que al menos te dirá (del lado del servidor) a qué país corresponde el rango de IPs de tu visitante. Es poco fidedigno de tanto que lleva sin actualizarse. Yo estoy en Chile y me marca como Colombia (donde está la matriz de IFX Networks)

**Si tienes control del dominio**

La obsolecencia de MaxDB puede suplirse con el uso de tu proveedor de DNS. Por ejemplo [Cloudflare le añade un header](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/es-es/articles/200168236--Qu%C3%A9-hace-la-geolocalizaci%C3%B3n-de-IP-de-Cloudflare-) `CF-Country-IP` con las dos letras de ISO 3166.

---

Estos workarounds debieras mandarlos al centroide del país, no te fies de las coordenadas si GeoIP te las da.